# c# 3rd working day excluding satuday and sunday

Tags: c#

```
private void btnDateTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DateTime trdCurrentMonth = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(DateTime.Today.Day - 3));
    if (trdCurrentMonth != 
        DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(DateTime.Today.Day)) &&
        trdCurrentMonth != DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(DateTime.Today.Day - 1))) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(trdCurrentMonth.ToString());
    }
}
```

How do I get the 3rd working day of current month, excluding Saturday and Sunday?

Answer (score 2):

Get weekdays in a first 10 calendar dates and `Skip` `2` to get the third working day in a month.

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2016,6,1); // 1st Day of the Month.
    var thirdWorkingDay = Enumerable.Range(0,10)
        .Select(x=> dt.AddDays(x))
        .Where(x=> x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        .Skip(2)
        .FirstOrDefault() ;
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vpWfCX)

Comment: I have checked the [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dxEUoX) with `2016,7,1` it gives me `7/3/2016` and is a sunday. Something wrong with the code, please check and update. Thank you

Comment: @un-lucky  Thanks for spotting it. fixed it.

Comment: We are here for supporting, so no need for thanks. Now the demo is fine `+1` for the updates

Answer (score 1):

I prefer you to keep a List of `DayOfWeek` to represent the holidays(here Saturday and Sunday). we can easily check whether the day is Saturday or Sunday. Then the first line will find the First day of the current month, Iterate through the days until we find the third working day. Now consider the code:

```
List<DayOfWeek> holydays = new List<DayOfWeek>() { DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Saturday };
DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.Year, DateTime.Now.Date.Month, 1); // first day of month
int thirdDay = 1;
int addDay = 0;
while (thirdDay <= 3)
{
    if (!holydays.Contains(firstDayOfMonth.AddDays(addDay++).DayOfWeek))
    {
        thirdDay++;
    }

}
DateTime thirdWorkingDay = firstDayOfMonth.AddDays(--addDay);
```

This will give

```
03/06/2016 for june - 2016
05/07/2016 for july- 2016
```